# Invalid inferred types

Tags: java, generics, ormlite

I'm just trying to write some Generic helper above database (ORMLite API), I compile it using Maven and build process failed with compilation

```
invalid inferred types for D; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
[ERROR] inferred: com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao<T,U>
[ERROR] bound(s): com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao<capture#2 of ?,?>
```

I try to build it with JDK 1.6 and also 1.7.

```
public class BaseDbHelper<T,U> extends DatabaseHelper<T, U> {

    private Dao<T, U> dao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<T, U> runtimeDao = null;
    Class<?> entityClass;

    public BaseDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        entityClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Dao<T, U> getDao() throws SQLException {
        if (dao == null) {
            // !!! ERROR
            dao = getDao(entityClass);
        }
        return dao;
    }

    @Override
    public RuntimeExceptionDao<T, U> getDataDao() {
        if (runtimeDao == null) {
            // !!! ERROR
            runtimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(entityClass);
        }
        return runtimeDao;
    }

}
```

Here is signature of two parent classes from lines marked with error

```
public <D extends com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao<T,?>, T>  D getRuntimeExceptionDao(java.lang.Class<T> clazz) { }

public <D extends com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao<T,?>, T>  D getDao(java.lang.Class<T> clazz) throws java.sql.SQLException { }
```

Comment: `entityClass` is of type `Class<?>` and `dao` is of type `Dao<T, U>` so the result of `getDao` will be of type `Dao<?,?>` which clearly does not coincide with `Dao<T, U>`, because the compiler simply does not know which type `?` represent.